# How to differenciate and store different lines from the given chunk of text?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface, sentence

**Description**
I want to separate the lines from the given chunk so that each line would represent a meaning full sentence or at least it won't change the other line by mixing it up. For example, I have this text :

```
515 Pacific Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90291, United States
(541) 754-3010 · email@email.com
MICHELLE LOPEZ, Fashion Designer
Expert Fashion Designer with 11+ years’ experience in women’s
high-end shoes. Launched product lines for Chanel and Gucci.
Designs showcased in Elle and Vogue. Attained recognition of
top seller fashionista in 2017.
```

The output should be :

```
(541) 754-3010 · email@email.com
MICHELLE LOPEZ, Fashion Designer
Expert Fashion Designer with 11+ years’ experience in women’s high-end shoes.
Launched product lines for Chanel and Gucci.
Designs showcased in Elle and Vogue. Attained recognition of top seller fashionista in 2017.
```

**My approach**

The text is separated using `\n` character and as the text contained that characters after "women's" (4th line) and "of" (6th line) , The solution of `\n` is not reliable.

I tried to separate using period `.` and for that approach the first line will be all joined until the full stop is found. So. this solution is not reliable as well.

After these scenarios, I tried to use machine learning using nltk and tokenizing the sentences. The result was the same with first line because I found this approach works same as dividing using period character.

The code for nltk:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.chunk import ne_chunk
from nltk.tree import Tree

# Sample text
text = """1515 Pacific Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90291, United States
(541) 754-3010 · test@example.com
MICHELLE LOPEZ, Fashion Designer
Expert Fashion Designer with 11+ years’ experience in women’s
high-end shoes Launched product lines for Chanel and Gucci
Designs showcased in Elle and Vogue Attained recognition of
top seller fashionista in 2017"""

# Remove new line characters
text = text.replace("\n", " ")

# Tokenize into sentences
sentences = sent_tokenize(text)

# Tokenize into words
tokenized_sentences = [word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]

# Part-of-speech tagging
pos_tagged_sentences = [pos_tag(tokens) for tokens in tokenized_sentences]

# Named Entity Recognition (NER)
ner_tagged_sentences = [ne_chunk(pos_tag(tokens)) for tokens in tokenized_sentences]

# Helper function to convert tagged sentence to tree format
def to_tree(chunked_sentence):
    return Tree(chunked_sentence.label(), [to_tree(c) if isinstance(c, Tree) else c[0] for c in chunked_sentence])

# Print the reconstructed sentences
for sentence, ner_tagged_sentence in zip(sentences, ner_tagged_sentences):
    reconstructed_sentence = " ".join(to_tree(ner_tagged_sentence).leaves())
    print(reconstructed_sentence)
```

**Expectations**

So, I want to process using nlp and I have actually visited the huggingface and looked through all the pipelines. But, unfortunately, cannot find a pipeline which could do this task. I may need to train some model, but, so far I have tried, different NER models which could only label the sentences so it does not work.